# When to use deleteLater

Tags: qt, message-queue

Assuming I have the following snippet, is it safe to call deleteLater in qto's destructor for other QT objects it might administer?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyQTObject qto;
    qto.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Because I've analyzed similar code like this with a leak detector and all the objects for which deleteLater was called, weren't deallocated correctly unless I replaced the call with a normal delete.
If I've understood this correctly, deleteLater only registers a deletion event in the QT message queue. Can this be the problem that qto's destructor is called at the end of main's scope whereas the QT message loop already ends with the return from a.exec? Thus the deletion event will never be processed, in fact not even pushed into a message queue since there is none?

Comment: you dont need deletelater on `qto`. it is on the stack. Btw analyzer can report false-positives.

Comment: @UmNyobe, the question asks if it is safe to call deleteLater...for OTHER QT object it might administer, not for qto itself.

Comment: This is quite simple to test. Just put some debug messages in the destructor and see if they show up. You will notice that they won't. Is there a reason these objects aren't children of `qto`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How delete and deleteLater works with regards to signals and slots in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888189/how-delete-and-deletelater-works-with-regards-to-signals-and-slots-in-qt)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I understand it, deleteLater is most often used when you require an object to be deleted from within the call to a slot. If delete is used in this case and the object is referenced when returning from the slot, a reference to uninitialised memory occurs.

Therefore, deleteLater requests that object to be deleted by placing a message on the event loop, which is processed at some point, on returning from the slot and it is safe to be deleted.

I expect that using deleteLater in the destructor means there's a likely chance that the object goes out of scope, calls deleteLater on its managed objects, but quits before the event loop has a chance to delete the objects, as exiting from QApplication::exec() will terminate the event loop.

Answer (score 22):

This post is rather aged, but I would like to add the answer I would have liked to come across when I was asking this myself.

`deleteLater()` can be very useful in combination with asynchronous operations. It especially shines, I think, with the more recent possibility to connect signals to lambda functions.

Suppose you have some `longComputation()` that you want to execute asynchronously (not in the sense of multithreading, in the sense of scheduling execution in the event loop). You can do like this:

```
void MyClass::deferLongComputation()
{
    QTimer* timer = new QTimer();

    connect(timer, 
            &QTimer::timeout,
            [this, timer](){this->longComputiation(); timer->deleteLater();});

    timer->setSingleShot(true);
    timer->start();
}
```

where `deleteLater()` takes care of safely disposing of the `QTimer` once its duty has been carried out and avoid the memory leak that one would have otherwise.

The same pattern can be used in multithreading with `QFutureWatcher`.

Comment: Would you please comment on why this is different than using the static :

`QTimer::singleShot(0, this, longComputation);`

Comment: @guitarpicva No difference in this simple example. `deleteLater()` is a fairly low-level feature and you can often find higher level constructs that do the job for you.

Comment: @guitarpicva You might prefer to implement the single shot manually in  some hypothetical use case where you want to setup the timer first and then fire it later on. (I haven't used Qt in quite a while and I don't remember specific use cases, but I remember I run into one or two during my Qt days)

Comment: I think `singleShot` sort of addresses that case as it is static and you can supply a wait time in the call.  I was just curious.  Your implementation looks a lot like the Qt documentation's explanation of what singleShot does.

I use `QTimer::singleShot` quite extensively working against serially and socket connected hardware devices.  One must often wait for them to "settle" before sending another command.

Thank you.

Comment: What if `this` is deleted before the timer times out? Will that not cause a crash unless we add `this` as a target to `connect(...)`? And then won't the `QTimer` be leaked?

Answer (score 8):

The question is old, but I'll leave this for the future generation) 
The reply which was marked as an answer is correct but oddly formulated.
Actually your question contains a right answer:

> message loop already ends with the return from a.exec? Thus the
>   deletion event will never be processed, in fact not even pushed into a
>   message queue since there is none.

This is exactly what is happening. Everything `deleteLater()` does is just posting a deletion event into the outter event loop. When event gets proccessed - object gets deleted. But if there are not outter event loop and no event loop is encountered later in the execution flow - event will never get posted, thus object is never deleted.

If you call `deleteLater()` in the object's destructor and put an object on the stack - `deleteLater()` is called when the object goes out of scope. In your example "going out of scope" is happening when closing brace of `main()` function is encountered. However, by that time, `a.exec()` (which represents the main event loop of Qt App) has already returned **-->** no event loop any more **-->** `deleteLater()` was called, but it's nowhere to post a deletion event **-->** objects were supposed to be "deletedLater" never get deleted...

Regarding the part "when to use deleteLater()":

**Kuba Ober** answered:

> Generally speaking, there is a narrow set of circumstances where
>   deleteLater should be used. Most likely you simply shouldn't be using
>   it...

Don't listen to it, it is absolutely incorrect as the whole answer. What you should do and what should not you better decide after reading [this article](http://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects). Although, it is mainly about Qt threads, the article also tells about ascynchronous programming (and, as **Emerald Weapon** mentioned, it is exactly what deleteLater() was created for).

Also, smart pointers and QObject parent ownership have nothing to do with scheduling for the deletion with `deleteLater()`. These both techniques are actually using a simple `delete` operation under the hood. And as the article shows and as **Emerald Weapon**'s answer demonstrated: `delete` does not solve the problems `deleteLater()` does. So if you need to delete object you use `delete`, if you need to schedule it for the deletion you use `deleteLater()`.

BTW, if you want to use smart pointer with `deleteLater()` you can specify the deleter:

```
// Shared Pointer
QSharedPointer<MyObject> obj = 
        QSharedPointer<MyObject>(new MyObject, &QObject::deleteLater);
// Scoped Pointer
QScopedPointer<MyObject, QScopedPointerDeleteLater> customPointer(new MyObject);
```

And at last, It is an **NOT** an error to use `deleteLater()` in the destructor of `QObject`, for non-child objects.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that the `deleteLater()` command is only executed by an event loop.

From the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qobject.html#deleteLater) for `QObject`:

> Schedules this object for deletion.
>
> The object will be deleted when control returns to the event
>   loop. If the event loop is not running when this function is
>   called (e.g. deleteLater() is called on an object before
>   QCoreApplication::exec()), the object will be deleted once the
>   event loop is started. If deleteLater() is called after the main event loop
>   has stopped, the object will not be deleted.
>   Since Qt 4.8, if deleteLater() is called on an object that lives in a
>   thread with no running event loop, the object will be destroyed when the
>   thread finishes.
>
> Note that entering and leaving a new event loop (e.g., by opening a modal
>   dialog) will \e not perform the deferred deletion; for the object to be
>   deleted, the control must return to the event loop from which
>   deleteLater() was called.
>
> **Note:** It is safe to call this function more than once; when the
>   first deferred deletion event is delivered, any pending events for the
>   object are removed from the event queue.

If you want all child `QObjects` to be deleted when `qto` is deleted, make sure they are created with `qto` as a the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, there is a narrow set of circumstances where deleteLater should be used. Most likely you simply shouldn't be using it.

It is an error to use it in the destructor of QObject, for non-child objects. As you've found QObjects may well be destructed without an event loop present. There are no `deleteLater` calls in object destructors the `qtbase` Qt module, for example.

One has to be careful here: for example, `~QTcpServer()` invokes `close()` invoking `d->socketEngine->deleteLater()`, but the socket engine is already a child of the server and will be deleted by `~QObject()` *anyway*.

For all I know, `MyQTObject` should be doing one of the following:

- using a smart pointer like `QScopedPointer` or `std::unique_ptr`,
- have the objects as regular (non-pointer) members,
- use raw pointers and have the objects be children of it.