# Qt MainWindow crashing

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qmainwindow, qt-signals

**Edit: I removed the destructor from the slot. But now I have memory leaking problems. Each new window that I open occupies some memory,and when I close it,the memory stays occupied**

When I execute the program,and open new windows, they are opened normally. When I close any of them, the whole application crashes (not only that specific window),and I get the crash error.

What am I doing wrong?

**mainWindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
class QHBoxLayout;
class QTextEdit;
class QWidget;
class QDialog;
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void closeWindow();
    void newWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MainWindow *tempMainWindow;
    QHBoxLayout * mainLyt;
    QTextEdit *txtEdit;
    QWidget *mainWidget;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainWindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QTextEdit>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mainWidget=new QWidget();
    mainLyt=new QHBoxLayout();
    txtEdit=new QTextEdit();
    mainLyt->addWidget(txtEdit);
    mainWidget->setLayout(mainLyt);
    setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
    connect(ui->actionExit,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(closeWindow()));
    connect(ui->actionNew,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(newWindow()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::closeWindow()
{
    this->close();
    delete txtEdit;
    delete mainLyt;
    delete mainWidget;
    this->~MainWindow();
}

void MainWindow::newWindow()
{
    tempMainWindow=new MainWindow(this);
    tempMainWindow->show();
}
```

Comment: `this->~MainWindow();` looks strange. What you intended to to with this call?

Comment: [Never delete object from slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888189/how-delete-and-deletelater-works-wrt-to-signals-and-slots-in-qt), especially in this wired manner. You are still inside a slot but the object which contains it does not exist.

Comment: @vahancho I thought that is the only way to stop the memory leaks,which occur when I open a new window,and close it,but the occupied memory doenst get released.
Ok,I'll remove the destructor part

Comment: Do not call the destructor explicitly ever, unless you deal with custom memory allocation and you have placement new, etc. IMHO, your whole logic is wrong. You are deleting items that could be children. If anything, you should delete the mainwindows in the main function or wherever you use them, but really, at this point, I do not even get why you have multiple main windows.

Comment: Read about `deleteLater()` method.

Comment: @LaszloPapp The thing is,I'm trying to make basic text editor,and when New is triggered, it should open a new window for new text document. Is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us see your code:

```
this->close();
delete txtEdit;
delete mainLyt;
delete mainWidget;
this->~MainWindow();
```

You are trying to destroy them and for the next open you allocate them almost the same way.

What you achieve here is basically performance penalty. I would suggest to hide, modify, and so on the unwanted items instead.

Comment: this->close();
    this->deleteLater();

I changed that slot and now it looks like this. But it seems that there are still memory leaks.

Comment: What I am telling you is delete or deleteLater does not make much sense since this can be reopened any time. What I advise instead, is to make modifications on close and open rather than brand new and delete cycles. Having that paradigm shift done, you will be able to utilize the Qt parent/child mechanism more, and forget the raw delete and deleteLater.

Comment: Ok,my constructor looks like this now(without new and delete stuff,static allocation only):

    {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWidget mainWidget();
    QHBoxLayout mainLyt();
    QTextEdit txtEdit();
    mainLyt.addItem(mainLyt);
    mainWidget.setLayout(mainLyt);
    setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
   
    }
But now bunch of errors occur.

Comment: There is no problem with heap objects so long as you allocate them in the constructor and delete them in the destructor. Do not forget to assign "this" as a parameter to their constructor though to enter the Qt child/parent hierarchy.

Comment: I think I missunderstood your previous comment. Instead of modifying open and close,I modified the constructor and created new objects (for QWidget,QTextEdit,and QHBoxLayout). I commented out the pointers.

Are you telling me to declare and initialize new objects (same as above) in the open() function and to use them instead of pointers in the constructor?

Comment: No... I am telling you not to construct anything in open, but the constructor, and the same change to the close and destructor.

Comment: @xpg94: have you finally moved all the delete in the destructor ... ? It is not a hard task, is it? :)

Comment: I can't believe that I actually didn't use destructor to delete pointed memory in the first place. Your last comment was like a cold shower. I modified it, yet there is still a memory leak.

Comment: I modified it again, and created the "factory" system of creating new windows,and it works as I wanted it to work now. No memory leaks anymore. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you pass to `QWidget()`, `QHBoxLayout()` and `QTextEdit()` also `this` (which is the parent), at the delection of the MainWindow Qt will delete for you the ui and all the additional widgets yur defined in the construstor. In this way you can avoid to call `closeWindow()` method.

`delete ui` is also not necessary.

```
ui->setupUi(this);
mainWidget = new QWidget(this);
mainLyt = new QHBoxLayout(this);
txtEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
```

Comment: The OP would like to delete in the closure function, not the destructor. The Qt parent/child hierarchy will not fix that. When you want to delete explicitly, i.e. not in the destructor, you do need either delete or deleteLater depending on the case.

Comment: I did as you suggested. I changed the actionExit connection to close() and added this as an argument to the three object you mentioned. But there is still a memory leak. The thing is, actually, even if I don't open a new window at all,if I only keep the firtly executed window opened and working, task manager shows that its memory consumption constantly grows. For 50-100 kb each 2-3 seconds. How could I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to make basic text editor,and when New is triggered, it should open a new window for new text document. Is there some better way to do this?

Yes. It's called a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29), and it can be a static method as it doesn't operate on any object. You can call it from a slot, of course.

I imagine you'll need to pass a file name to the newly created window - that could be an argument to the factory method and the factory slot. If the "new" window is empty, then this is not an issue.

Other issues:

1. There is no reason to keep the `mainWidget` member: it is always available as `centralWidget()`.
2. There's also no reason to have the members other than `ui` as pointers. It is actually a premature pessimization - it will waste a bit more heap memory.
3. You don't need a layout for the central widget if it has no child widgets. The `QTextEdit` instance itself can be the central widget.
4. The `ui` instance should be retained using a smart pointer. This makes the destructor completely compiler-generated (it has an empty body).
5. You don't need anything fancy in the `closeWindow` slot. Simply delete the instance!

```cpp
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();
  static MainWindow * createWindow();
  void setFileName(const QString & fileName);
public slots:
  void closeWindow();
  void newWindow();
private:
  QScopedPointer<Ui::MainWindow> const ui;
  QTextEdit m_txtEdit;
};

void MainWindow::newWindow() {
   createWindow()->show();
}

void MainWindow::closeWindow() {
  deleteLater();
}

MainWindow * MainWindow::createWindow(QWidget * parent) {
  return new MainWindow(parent);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  setCentralWidget(&m_txtEdit);
  connect(ui->actionExit, SIGNAL(triggered()), SLOT(closeWindow()));
  connect(ui->actionNew, SIGNAL(triggered()), SLOT(newWindow()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{}
```

Comment: Thank you a million times. I did as you said,and even the memory leak error is fixed. Program works perfectly now.
Should I use the "factory" way for creating objects of each new class that I will use in future?

Comment: @xpg94 It's just one way of many. What you were doing is something very, very weird that makes no sense. There's no reason to create the new window by messing up an existing one.